# Design an Object-Oriented representation to model the components of a computer?

Tags: object-oriented-analysis

Object-oriented design is frequently asked in interviews and classes, this (designing a computer) has been bugging me for days and I still can't think of a decent way to model it.

What should the classes be and what states and signals should each class have?

Comment: Depends to what level of abstraction you want to model. You could use only one class `Computer` that does everything. You could create classes `Cpu`, `Ram`, etc. You could create classes `Transistor`, `NandGate`, etc and model it to the level of circuits.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good place to start is by studying the architecture of an operating system kernel, such as Linux. A kernel has to interact with computer hardware so it must have *some* model of various computer components.